# need a query to pull from another table

Tags: php, eloquent

I have a table called (orders) which collects the id's from other tables but now i want to display field data from one of the other tables called (products) this the query i have made but doesn't work.
the page loads but nothing displays

i am working in laravel using eloquent model

```
$products = DB::table('products')->where('id', '=',  'orders.product_id' )->get();

return view('thankyou', compact(['ordered', 'products' ,'product']));
```

on the thank you page i have this code:

```
@foreach($products as $purss)

 <tr>                                                                                 
  <td>{{$purss->id}}</td> 

  <td>{{ $purss->plant }}</td>

  <td>{{ $purss->price  }}</td>

 </tr>

@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from where you get `orders.product_id` it acts like it was a variable, and it is not .
it seems your query dosn't see this statement `orders.product_id`. in this case you need to `join` tables.

```
$products = DB::table('products')
            ->join('orders', 'products.id', '=', 'orders.product_id')
            ->get();
```